# Escape multiple nested functions in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, es6-promise

I have code in Javascript that looks like this:

```
function someFunction() {
    // Code
    somePromise().catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });
    // Mode Code
}
```

I would like to escape both `somePromise().catch` and `someFunction()` in the event that `somePromise()` is rejected. I tried using `return` but that only allows me to escape `somePromise().catch`. Is there any function that would allow me to break out of nested loops?

Comment: How about not catching somePromise? (Removing . catch())

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not an option I can use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by using `async`/`await`:

```
function async someFunction() {
    // Code
    try {
        await somePromise();
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return; // aborts further execution
    }
    // More Code
}
```

See [async function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Async/await solves the problem but it's important to understand why it solves the problem.

Promises are a mechanism for storing continuations. Functions you pass to `then` and `catch` are stored within the promise and are executed when the promise is resolved.

To solve this without `async`/`await`, you would simply return the Promise and use `then` to execute any code that should execute when the Promise does not reject:

```
function someFunction() {
    // Code
    return somePromise()
      .then(result => {
        // More Code
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
}
```

This is essentially what `async`/`await` de-sugars to. Async/await is syntactic sugar around a state machine that wires up these continuations for you.